# Deriving barycentric coordinates of the isotomic conjugate

Tags: euclidean-geometry, barycentric-coordinates

Consider a triangle $ABC$ and a point $P=(x:y:z)$(in Barycentric coordinates). If $P^t$ is the isotomic conjugate of $P$ prove that

$$P^t=\left(\frac{1}{x}:\frac{1}{y}:\frac{1}{z}\right)$$
Note that $$( u : v : w)=\left(\frac{u}{u+v+w} , \frac{v}{u+v+w}, \frac{w}{u+v+w}\right)$$

Now since

$$x=\frac{[PBC]}{[ABC]}, \quad y=\frac{[PCA]}{[BCA]}, \quad z=\frac{[PAB]}{[CAB]}$$
We should have
$$\frac{[ABC]}{[P^tBC]}=\frac{[PBC]}{[ABC]}\text{ etc...}$$
But I have no idea how to prove it.
Here is the diagram [image]

Comment: You can derive the coordinates of isotomic conjugate, in nicer ways, without using the area definition of barycentric coordinates.

Comment: In what coordinate system?

Comment: In the system of barycentric coordinates.

Comment: Then how? @ZNatox

Comment: Well, you just have to notice that $M=(0:1:1)$
$G=(0:y:z)$ (This is a well known fact, check EGMO), and $D=\frac{G+G'}2$ (With normalized coordinates) Thus $G'=2D-G$. We know that the general equation of a line in barycentric coordinates is of the form:$px+qy+rz=0$ for some $p,q,r$. Plugging in $G'$ and $A$, you get the equation of line $(GA)$. Doing the same thing for other lines, and intersecting them, you get the coordinates of isotomic conjugate.

Comment: Sorry, you get the equation of line $(G'A)$, not $(GA)$.

Answer (score 1):

I will write as usual $(x,y,z)$ for the (normed) barycentric coordinates of a point if $x+y+z=1$, else $(x:y:z)$ is defined if the sum $S:=x+y+z\ne 0$, and this point corresponds to $(x/S,y/S,z/S)$.

Start with $P=(x,y,z)$.
Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
G &= (0:y:z)\ , & G'&=(0:z:y)=\left(0:\frac 1y:\frac 1z\right)\ ,\\
H &= (x:0:z)\ , & H'&=(z:0:x)=\left(\frac 1x:0:\frac 1z\right)\ ,\\
I &= (x:y:0)\ , & I'&=(y:x:0)=\left(\frac 1x:\frac 1y:0\right)\ ,\\
\end{aligned}
$$
and it is clear that the claimed point
$$
\left(\frac 1x:\frac 1y:\frac 1z\right)
$$
is on $AG'$, on $BH'$, and on $CI'$.

$\square$